# Not able to fetch LedgerList data in an XML request from Tally

Tags: xml, tally, tdl

While exporting data from Tally, I'm not able to fetch the ledger details of the invoice.

I am only able to fetch the outer-level details.

I tried with Walk by: Ledger Entries, but it does not come under the Voucher tag. How can I make it possible?

Also, I am having a big doubt about the form, part, and line work flow.

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>Data</TYPE>
    <ID>DaybookGR</ID>
</HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG>
                <CURRENTCOMPANY>${company}</CURRENTCOMPANY>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                <SVFROMDATE>${fromDate}</SVFROMDATE>
                <SVTODATE>${toDate}</SVTODATE>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <REPORT NAME="DaybookGR">
                        <FORMS>DaybookGR</FORMS>
                        <TITLE>DaybookGR </TITLE>
                    </REPORT>
                    <FORM NAME="DaybookGR">
                        <TOPPARTS>DaybookGR</TOPPARTS>
                        <XMLTAG>"TallyGraphs"</XMLTAG>
                    </FORM>
                    <PART NAME="DaybookGR">
                        <TOPLINES>Daybook Line Title, Daybook Details</TOPLINES>
                        <REPEAT>Daybook Details : GetLedgerCollAmt</REPEAT>
                        <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                        <COMMONBORDERS>Yes</COMMONBORDERS>
                    </PART>
                    <PART NAME="Ledgerlist Line Title">
                     <TOPLINES>Ledgerlist Line Title,Ledger Details</TOPLINES>
                        <REPEAT>Ledger Details : GetLedger</REPEAT>
                        <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                        <COMMONBORDERS>Yes</COMMONBORDERS>
                    </PART>
                    <LINE NAME="Daybook Line Title">
                        <USE>Daybook Details</USE>
                        <LOCAL>Field : Default : Type : String </LOCAL>
                        <LOCAL>Field : Field Amount : Set as: "Amount"</LOCAL>
                    </LINE>
                    <LINE NAME="Ledgerlist Line Title">
                        <USE>Ledger Details</USE>
                        <LOCAL>Field : Default : Type : String </LOCAL>
                        <LOCAL>Field : Field Amount : Set as: "Amount"</LOCAL>
                    </LINE>
                    <LINE NAME="Daybook Details">
                        <LEFTFIELDS>PartyLedgerName</LEFTFIELDS>
                        <RIGHTFIELDS>vchType,VoucherNumber,Amount,Date</RIGHTFIELDS>
                        <XMLTAG>Voucher</XMLTAG>
                        <EXPLODE>Ledgerlist Line Title</EXPLODE>
                        <BELONGSTO>YES</BELONGSTO>
                    </LINE>
                    <LINE NAME="Ledger Details">
                        <LEFTFIELDS>PartyLedgerName</LEFTFIELDS>
                        <XMLTAG>LedgerList</XMLTAG>
                    </LINE>
                    <FIELD NAME="PartyLedgerName">
                        <USE>Name Field</USE>
                        <SET>$LedgerName</SET>
                    </FIELD>
                   <FIELD NAME="Date">
                        <USE>Long Date Field</USE>
                        <SET>$$DDMMYYYYDateFormat:$Date:"-"</SET>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="VoucherNumber">
                        <USE>Name Field</USE>
                        <SET>$VoucherNumber</SET>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="Amount">
                        <USE>Amount Field</USE>
                        <SET>$Amount</SET>
                    </FIELD>

                    <COLLECTION NAME="AllVouchers" ISMODIFY="No">
                        <TYPE>Voucher</TYPE>
                        <BELONGSTO>YES</BELONGSTO>
                    </COLLECTION>
                    <COLLECTION NAME="GetLedger" ISMODIFY="No">
                    <walk>Ledger</walk>
                        <BELONGSTO>YES</BELONGSTO>
                            <FILTER>IsOptionalFilter</FILTER>
                              <FETCH>PartyLedgerName</FETCH>
                        </COLLECTION>
                    <COLLECTION NAME="GetLedgerCollAmt" ISMODIFY="No">
                            <SourceCOLLECTION>AllVouchers</SourceCOLLECTION>
                            <FILTER>IsOptionalFilter</FILTER>
                              <FETCH>VoucherNumber,LedgerName,Amount,VoucherTypeName,Date</FETCH>
                        </COLLECTION>
                        <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="IsOptionalFilter">NOT $IsOptional</SYSTEM>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

My expected output structure is:

```
`<TALLYGRAPHS>
        <VOUCHER>
              <PARTYLEDGERNAME></PARTYLEDGERNAME>
              <VOUCHERTYPENAME></VOUCHERTYPENAME>
              <VOUCHERNUMBER></VOUCHERNUMBER>
              <AMOUNT></AMOUNT>
              <DATE></DATE>
            <Ledgerlist>........</Ledgerlist>
            <Ledgerlist>........</Ledgerlist>
         </VOUCHER>
         <VOUCHER>
                 <PARTYLEDGERNAME></PARTYLEDGERNAME>
                  <VOUCHERTYPENAME></VOUCHERTYPENAME>
                  <VOUCHERNUMBER></VOUCHERNUMBER>
                   <AMOUNT></AMOUNT>
                    <DATE></DATE>
            <Ledgerlist>........</Ledgerlist>
            <Ledgerlist>........</Ledgerlist>
         </VOUCHER>
    </TALLYGRAPHS>`
```

Comment: Related: *[Can "doubt" sometimes mean "question"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want control of fields you want in Ledger Entries, then you have to take everything into control.

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>Data</TYPE>
        <ID>DaybookGR</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG>
                <CURRENTCOMPANY>${company}</CURRENTCOMPANY>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                <SVFROMDATE>${fromDate}</SVFROMDATE>
                <SVTODATE>${toDate}</SVTODATE>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <REPORT NAME="DaybookGR">
                        <FORMS>DaybookGR</FORMS>
                        <TITLE>DaybookGR </TITLE>
                    </REPORT>
                    <FORM NAME="DaybookGR">
                        <TOPPARTS>DaybookGR</TOPPARTS>
                        <XMLTAG>"TallyGraphs"</XMLTAG>
                    </FORM>
                    <PART NAME="DaybookGR">
                        <TOPLINES>Daybook Line Title, Daybook Details</TOPLINES>
                        <REPEAT>Daybook Details : GetLedgerCollAmt</REPEAT>
                        <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                        <COMMONBORDERS>Yes</COMMONBORDERS>
                    </PART>
                    <PART NAME="Ledgerlist Line Title">
                        <TOPLINES>Ledger Details</TOPLINES>
                        <REPEAT>Ledger Details:LedgerEntries</REPEAT>
                        <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                        <COMMONBORDERS>Yes</COMMONBORDERS>
                    </PART>
                    <LINE NAME="Daybook Line Title">
                        <USE>Daybook Details</USE>
                        <LOCAL>Field : Default : Type : String </LOCAL>
                        <LOCAL>Field : Field Amount : Set as: "Amount"</LOCAL>
                    </LINE>
                    <LINE NAME="Ledgerlist Line Title">
                        <USE>Ledger Details</USE>
                        <LOCAL>Field : Default : Type : String </LOCAL>
                        <LOCAL>Field : Field Amount : Set as: "Amount"</LOCAL>
                    </LINE>
                    <LINE NAME="Daybook Details">
                        <LEFTFIELDS>PartyLedgerName</LEFTFIELDS>
                        <RIGHTFIELDS>vchType,VoucherNumber,Amount,Date</RIGHTFIELDS>
                        <XMLTAG>Voucher</XMLTAG>
                        <EXPLODE>Ledgerlist Line Title</EXPLODE>
                    </LINE>
                    <LINE NAME="Ledger Details">
                        <LEFTFIELDS>PartyLedgerName</LEFTFIELDS>
                        <XMLTAG>LedgerList</XMLTAG>
                    </LINE>
                    <FIELD NAME="PartyLedgerName">
                        <USE>Name Field</USE>
                        <SET>$LedgerName</SET>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="Date">
                        <USE>Long Date Field</USE>
                        <SET>$$DDMMYYYYDateFormat:$Date:"-"</SET>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="VoucherNumber">
                        <USE>Name Field</USE>
                        <SET>$VoucherNumber</SET>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="Amount">
                        <USE>Amount Field</USE>
                        <SET>$Amount</SET>
                    </FIELD>
                    <COLLECTION NAME="AllVouchers" ISMODIFY="No">
                        <TYPE>Voucher</TYPE>
                        <BELONGSTO>YES</BELONGSTO>
                    </COLLECTION>
                    
                    <COLLECTION NAME="GetLedgerCollAmt" ISMODIFY="No">
                        <SourceCOLLECTION>AllVouchers</SourceCOLLECTION>
                        <FILTER>IsOptionalFilter</FILTER>
                        <FETCH>VoucherNumber,LedgerName,Amount,VoucherTypeName,Date,Ledgerentries.*</FETCH>
                    </COLLECTION>
                    <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="IsOptionalFilter">NOT $IsOptional</SYSTEM>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

If you don't want control of fields in Ledger Entries then use below XML

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION> 1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>
        <ID>AllVouchers</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <EXPLODEFLAG>Yes</EXPLODEFLAG>
                <CURRENTCOMPANY>${company}</CURRENTCOMPANY>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                <SVFROMDATE>${fromDate}</SVFROMDATE>
                <SVTODATE>${toDate}</SVTODATE>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                   
                    <COLLECTION NAME="AllVouchers" ISMODIFY="No">
                        <TYPE>Voucher</TYPE>
                        <FETCH>LedgerEntries.*</FETCH>
                        <BELONGSTO>YES</BELONGSTO>
                    </COLLECTION>
                    
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Comment: Getting response like this <RESPONSE>Unknown Request, cannot be processed</RESPONSE>

Comment: @Abisha check now with updated xml, previously version tag is missing

Comment: I want ledger entries in field only. I tried with adding part, But is not working correctly. Kindly check the above code

Comment: @Abisha I fixed your XML,
Ledgerentries are sub collection in Voucher , so you didn't required defining other collection separately,

Comment: Absolutely right thank you sir

Comment: If i supposed to add inventory details means where i have to include <EXPLODE>Inventory Line Title</EXPLODE> tag

Comment: Same as you did for ledger list, i.e., in Line- Daybook Details

Comment: The first sentence is nearly incomprehensible. Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73411957/edit) it? (Burt *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)